# Tracking progress of AWS Polly speech

Tags: amazon-polly

Is there an event or something that could be used to indicate what word is being spoken currently?

I can't find anything in the documentation but I want to double check.

I need that so, e.g., it's possible to move back X words.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polly can generate speech marks, i.e. the position and timing of each word. Using this information, you could certainly achieve what you have in mind.

To generate speech marks, simply call the SynthesizeSpeech API using the 'json' output format.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/using-speechmarks.html

Comment: This means we need to pay 2x, right? once for mp3 and once for the json. @Julien